# bash and grep: passing of regex parameter

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to write a bash script that helps solving crosswords. For example, the question is "Alcoholic Drink in German". I already have a 'B' at the first place, an 'R' at the last place and two gaps in between. So a regex would be $B..R^
Since I live in Switzerland, I'd like to use the ngerman dictionary (DICT=/usr/share/dict/ngerman).
Here's how I'd do it directly on the shell:

```bash
    grep -i '^B...$' /usr/share/dict/ngerman
```

That works perfectly, and the word 'Bier' appears among three others. Since this syntax is cumbersome, I'd like to write a little batch script, that allows me to enter it like this:

```bash
    crosswords 'B..R'
```

Here's my approach:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

DICT=/usr/share/dict/ngerman

usage () {
    progname=$(basename $0)
    echo "usage: $progname regex"
}

if [ $# -le 0 ]; then 
    usage
    exit 1
fi

regex="'^$1$'"
cmd="grep -i $regex $DICT"
echo $regex
echo $cmd
$($cmd) | while read word; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

But nothing appears, it doesn't work. I also output the `$regex` and the `$cmd` variable for debugging reasons. Here's what comes out:

'^B..R$'

```bash
grep -i '^B..R$' /usr/share/dict/ngerman
```

That's exactly what I need. If I copy/paste the command above, it works perfectly. But if i call it with `$($cmd)`, it fails.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, now I got it. When I do it manually, '' are expanded! Here's my test program in C (param-test.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I call:

```
    param-test 'foo'
```

And I see:

```
    foo
```

That's the problem! grep doesn't really get 'B..R', but just B..R.

Comment: In [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2698019/aleks-daniel-jakimenko) I have provided you with a [link to the page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) that explains that kind of stuff. Here is another good one: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: OK, thanks. There is so much introductory stuff on the web and in books, but the "darker corners" of the syntax are seldom explained, especially for bash. This sites look better in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

Change `regex="^'$1$'"` to `regex="^$1$"` and `$($cmd)` to `$cmd`

Here is a fixed version:

```
#!/bin/bash

DICT=/usr/share/dict/ngerman

usage () {
    progname=$(basename "$0")
    echo "usage: $progname regex"
}

if [ $# -le 0 ]; then 
    usage
    exit 1
fi

regex="^$1$"
cmd="grep -i $regex $DICT"
echo "$regex"
echo "$cmd"
$cmd | while read -r word; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

But this script has potential problems. For example try running it as `./script 'asdads * '`. This will expand to all files in a directory and all of them are going to be passed to grep.

Here is a bit improved version of your code with correct quoting and also with **bonus** input validation:

```
#!/bin/bash

DICT=/usr/share/dict/ngerman

usage () {
    progname=$(basename "$0")
    echo "usage: $progname regex"
}

if [ $# -le 0 ]; then 
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z\.]+$ ]]; then
    echo 'Wrong word. Please use only a-zA-Z characters and dots for unknown letters'
    exit 1
fi

grep -i "^$1$" "$DICT" | while read -r word; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like this. But I just don't understand why. In general, it's a good habit to pass regex to grep by quoting them. And if I enter the command manually quoted, it works perfectly. But why can't the shell handle this? I don't understand.

Comment: @PatrickBucher the problem was that your regex had ``'`` symbols inside like a part of matching pattern. So your code was searching for ``'b..r'`` instead of ``b..r``. [Read this page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) about bash quoting

Comment: But I output exactly what I pass to grep. And the quotes are just to delimit the parameter, so they're now part of the regex, they just delimit the regex. But there must be a difference in calling grep inside a script with $cmd and to calling grep 'manually'. The only thing that bugs me, is that I don't understand the reason it doesn't work. But thanks for the input validation, that will be important vor version 2 of the script :-)
When outputting the $cmd variable, I see: grep '^B..R$' and not grep ''^B..R$''

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to put quotes around regex variable string. and `$($cmd)` should change to `$cmd`

so the correct code is :

```
#!/bin/bash

DICT=/usr/share/dict/ngerman

usage () {
    progname=$(basename $0)
    echo "usage: $progname regex"
}

if [ $# -le 0 ]; then 
    usage
    exit 1
fi

regex="^$1$"
cmd="grep -i $regex $DICT"
echo $regex
echo $cmd
$cmd | while read word; do
    echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. It's much simpler like this.